# Custom UIView size position and IBaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgrectmake

Good evening ,

I'm working on app that has to show (when a button is clicked) a custom container in a precise position and size over my ViewController.

This container will load 2 checkboxs (I know that I can use a UISwitchControl and modify the 2 states with PNGs)and a button "Submit" .

I'm new on iOS dev , please help me create this layout (see attachement) and how to check which checkboxes are checked when I press submit, sample code are much appreciated .[image: View to create]

Thank you all .

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the `BOOL` variable. When you click the Item1, it should be YES and when you click the Item2, it should be NO. Code is followed,

```
BOOL item1ORitem2 = YES;
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[containerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];

UIButton *item1btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[item1btn setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 50, 30)];
[item1btn addTarget:self action:@selector(item1btnAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[containerView addSubview:item1btn];

UIButton *item2btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[item2btn setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 50, 30)];
[item2btn addTarget:self action:@selector(item2btnAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[containerView addSubview:item2btn];

UIButton *submitBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[submitBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 50, 30)];
[submitBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(submitBtnAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[containerView addSubview:submitBtn];
```

the methods are,

```
-(void)item1btnAction
{
    item1ORitem2 = YES;
}
-(void)item2btnAction
{
    item1ORitem2 = NO;
}
-(void)submitBtnAction
{
    NSLog(@"item1ORitem2");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , is it possible to do this by using a nib file ? and a .h and .m files ? I mean : create the view as a nib and set all the logic in the controlling class ?

Answer (score 0):

1) In your xib file you need to drag and drop 2 buttons and set its type to custom.

2) You should have 2 images checked and unchecked of the boxes.

3) You then need to change the state of the button to normal/default and set the image to checked.png(or what ever ur image name is).

4) Then change the state to selected and set image to unchecked.png(or whatever the name is of ur unchecked box image).

so now you have 2 images 1 for selected state and other for normal state.

5) You can keep the method for both the buttons seperately 
for eg:

```
-(IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender {
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
if (btn.isSelected) {
    [btn setSelected:NO];
}
else {
    [btn setSelected:YES];
}
}
```

This will toggle the button state when you press it.

You can call this same method on both buttons.

**Update**

6) Now you can set outlets of each checkbox button in the Interface Builder using this link:
[Setting Outlets](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/iphone-programming-fundamentals-outlets-and-actions).

7) In the submit button method you can check if the buttons are checked or not using the following code. Suppose your checkbox uibutton ivar is name check1 & check2

```
-(IBAction)submitPressed:(id)sender {
if (check1.isSelected) {
    //Check button is unchecked
}
else {
    //Check button is checked
}

if (check2.isSelected) {
    //Check button is unchecked
}
else {
    //Check button is checked
}

}
```

DONE !! Good luck..

Comment: thank you for your answer , but how to make this view appear and set it's position over my viewController ?